# No visible overloaded '=' in C++ vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign a value to a vector, but I get this error. What is the issue about?

```
std::vector<bool> *boolVec = new std::vector<bool>(max, true);
boolVec[0] = false;
```

This code works:

```
boolVec->at(0) = false;
```

Comment: `ptr[index]` is equivalent with `*(ptr + index)`, so `boolVec[0]` is the same as `*boolVec`. You are trying to assign a `bool` to the vector itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially resolvable by paying attention.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to `new` the vector? `std::vector<bool> boolVec(max, true);` probably does what you want.

Comment: The advantages of not using `new` are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/509868)

Comment: Dont add the answer to the question. If you think doing `boolVec->at` is the answer then add it as an answer, but know that `->at(` is not equivalent to `operator[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pointer to a vector `std::vector<bool> *boolVec` This is not what you want. Just use a vector:

```
std::vector<bool> boolVec(max, true);
boolVec[0] = false;
```

The vector data will be stored on the heap.

If you truely need the pointer then you need to dereference it. You can use

```
(*boolVec)[0] = false;
```

or

```
 boolVec->at(0) = false;
```

Note that using `->at(` will perform boundary checks and may be slower.

Comment: This initializes vector on stack, I may have very large vector size, thus I want to create it on heap. I also don't want to just push the value to vector, but set a specific value at index.

Comment: @Dvole: The part that holds the bools goes on the heap either way.

Comment: @Dvole The heavy part will be on the heap. This is absolutley what you want, dont make a pointer to a vector.

Comment: @Ben Thats something I always wanted to know but never dared to ask ;).

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: There certainly are reasons to have a pointer to a vector, but the stated one is not one of them.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Id love an example of a reason. Only thing i can think of is passing over physical interfaces or something crazy like that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Ben: Same reason you'd want a pointer to anything else. As a non-owning reassignable/nullable reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, while I totally agree one might need a pointer to vector, I really have hard time trying to come with a valid scenario of dynamically creating a vector object. Just see no reason to.

Comment: @SergeyA: I'm only talking about the pointer part, not the dynamic allocating part. Although I can certainly also think of scenarios where I would want to dynamically allocate a vector, it would never be of the form `vector<...>* vp = new vector<...>;`. It might come in the form of `std::vector<std::vector<...>> vv;`. I would, in fact, never use `new` for anything (other than placement new), even when I want dynamically allocated raw memory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, interesting approach. How would you design a container of polymorphic types?

Comment: @SergeyA: Okay, you got me. I was using hyperbole when I said "never". I'll use it when it is the most convenient interface (for your example, it would be a container of `unique_ptr`, which would result in using `new` before `std::make_unique` existed). But if `unique_ptr` didn't already exist, I would not implement my version of it using allocating new. It would just use `malloc` with placement new.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
(*boolVec)[0] = false;
```

You have a *pointer* to a vector, so you have to dereference the pointer first.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use the subscript operator

For example

```
( *boolVec )[0] = false;
```

or

```
boolVec[0][0] = false;
```

or

```
boolVec->operator []( 0 ) = false;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>


int main( void )
{
    std::vector<bool> *boolVec = new std::vector<bool>( 6, true );

    boolVec[0][0] = false;
    ( *boolVec )[2] = false;
    boolVec->operator []( 4 ) = false;

    for ( bool b : *boolVec ) std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete boolVec;
}


false true false true false true
```

Consider also a possibility to define tha vector like

```
std::vector<bool> boolVec( 6, true );
```